# Tag synonym request: o2-sensor and lambda-sensor

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We ought to have [o2-sensor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/o2-sensor) and [lambda-sensor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-sensor) as synonyms.

The former is more commonplace in street parlance, the latter is the more technically-correct term for this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Entered - go vote for it!

*Man, the one time that I want to be brief, Stackexchange says "No, more characters!!!!"*

**EDIT:** You can vote for it at [this link](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags/o2-sensor/synonyms).

Comment: Voted. Thanks Bob.

Answer (score 1):

Haha ... I just tried to enter it in as a synonym, but it wouldn't let me. I agree with your assertion, though. They should be synonyms.